# Standard normal cummulative distribution function in PHP 8

Tags: php, statistics, pecl

Is there a php function for the standard normal cumulative distribution function in PHP 8? I know there is an extensions PECL STATS with function stats_cdf_normal(), but that extensions is not running on PHP 8.

Can somebody help me with a formula for the standard normal cumulative distribution? (or help me to get PHP STATS working in PHP 8)

Comment: You're not likely to easily get that stats module running on PHP 8+, my recommendation would be to look for a library on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) that does the same. Perhaps [markrogoyski/math-php](https://github.com/markrogoyski/math-php).

Comment: Well, the standard normal cdf is equal to (1 + erf(x/sqrt(2)))/2 if I remember correctly (I guess you should check it), where erf = Gaussian error function, which is a built-in function in many math libraries, but not, it appears, in PHP ... One approach could be to implement a simple approximation to erf via rational functions or rational times exp or something. If you are embedding this in a web page, then maybe the accuracy for a simple approximation is tolerable.